# GSM command AT+ULOC gives wrong Info?

Tags: gsm, at-command

I have a gsm system and suddenly from some months ago I am getteing wrong info from AT+ULOC.

> 01.01.2004,07:00:05.000,130.0000000,40.0000000,0,800000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Sometimes it sends correct info but most of the time is wrong.
I am using SARA-G3 series and my setting are
`AT+ULOCCELL=1` 
and
`AT+ULOC=2,2,1,60,1000`

I will be thankful for any help iun this regard.

Thank you,

What I tried?!
To check another sim card and it was OK.
I contacted the Sim provider and they say the issue is within my system. But I do not know if the SARA has issue or this command is outdated. Because it was ok before.